# Compiler error with win32 COORD structure?

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to implement a progress bar for a console application in windows using Win32 Console API. My problem is that the compiler gives the error, `error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'`. The relevant code is as follows.

```
void updateBar(PBAR * pbr, float ratio){
    COORD pos;
    pos.X = 0;
    pos.Y = 25;

    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConOut, pos);
}
```

`COORD` is the Win32 structure for denoting a co-ordinate pair. `hConOut` is a global variable and `PBAR` is a structure. Above error is given twice for two assignments (pos.X = 0 an pox.Y = 25). If I use the following, it compiles perfectly.

```
void updateBar(PBAR * pbr, float ratio){
    COORD pos = {0, 25};
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConOut, pos);
}
```

I really can't understand the reason for this. I mean it's just an assignment to structure members, right ?? If I do something like `POINT pt; pt.x = 0; pt.y = 25`, it compiles perfectly. `POINT` is just another structure.

I use visual studio 2010 on windows 7 and compiler is:

Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for 80x86

Any thoughts ?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I compiled this and it works fine.

However, if I define X or Y as macros, e.g.

```
#define X 2
#define Y 15
```

then I get exactly the same error as you.  Do you have these macros?

Comment: God !! I have the same macros! Thanks a lot

Comment: @arx - beat me to it by a minute. Time to delete my answer!

Comment: @user1671516 - then try `static const int X = 100;` instead!

Comment: @Roddy - I just renamed those macros. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Error C2059 is a parse error, the constant is unexpected. You probably have some garbage character somewhere, a mis-matched brace earlier in the file, or something.

See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8xe60cf%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> syntax error : 'token'
>
> The token caused a syntax error.
>
> To determine the cause, examine not only the line listed in the error message, but also the lines above it.